# CSS column devilry: a sticky div with an auto-stretching div in between it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I should start by saying I have researched this question. I can't find any identical questions or ones which do what I'm after.

I'd like to be able to put some content at the bottom left of the page, and then have a div above that which automatically stretches itself to use all the space between the top of the page and the content at the bottom left, even when the user resizes the window.

Please see the image below.

I position the bottom-left content with `position: absolute; bottom: 10px;`, which works. So then I would ideally have the div above it automatically stretch to fill the big gap (i.e.):

`[stretchy_div_height] = [100%] - [height_of_bottom_div] - [bottom_div_margin]`.

Ideally I would like to do this without JavaScript if possible. But either way is fine. I can't use faux columns for the height-stretching div (I need real content all the way down).

Thank you!

Here is an image of what I'm aiming to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/zSeLS/

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 60px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #ccc
}
#leftButton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background: #f0f
}

#content {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 140px;
    background: #999
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="leftButton"></div>

<div id="content">
    some content<br />
    ..
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you very much. Just out of interest - how easy would it be to alter this so that the #content wraps to directly underneath the #leftButton if its height is greater than the initial page frame? That is, if I have lots of #content, can it wrap to the left, underneath #leftButton? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, an update: in Chrome this seems to behave differently. The space between #left and #leftButton is considerably larger than on Firefox, and although #leftButton moves with the window resize, the #left div does not, meaning the bottom of it is left dangling below the window on a resize. Weird!

Answer (score 1):

thirtydot's solution is good, but sometimes I find absolute positioning of the containing elements to be a little too inflexible, e.g. if you want to center your layout. You can still make it work that way, but as an alternative, you can float the relevant elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  html {
    height:100%;
  }
  body {
    height:99%;
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
  }
  #left-top {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    background:#ffcccc;
  }
  #left-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    background:#ccffcc;
  }
  #right {
    float:left;
    width:600px;
    background:#ccccff;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id='left-top'>
    <p>Left</p>
    <div id='left-bottom'>Bottom</div>
  </div>

  <div id='right'>
    <p>Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content Arbitrary content</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This almost worked! But it resulted in a vertical scrollbar appearing and the #left-bottom being rendered just below the view of the screen. Strange. I will experiment with this further, though. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, that's puzzling. I purposely set <body>'s height to 99% to have a gap at the bottom -- all elements should be entirely visible with no scrollbar (unless you shrink your window's width below 800px, in which case you'd get a horizontal scrollbar). I can't think of what would be pushing things down. Did you modify the CSS at all? What browser are you seeing this in?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a div which will include both the div for the left column and its footer..

like

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
  <div id="columnleft></div>
  <div id="footerleft"></div>
  <div>
  <div id="right"></div>
<div>

did you try it already?
```

Comment: I did try this, but couldn't get the CSS. Thank you anyway! :)